# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll ?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a class DBConnectionClass and some associated classes . 
I have aan InsertQueryMethod whish is as follows

```
      public string InsertQuery
    {
        get { return InsertQuery; }
        set { InsertQuery = schools.SchoolsInsertQuery +                         branches.BranchInsertQuery + students.StudentsInsertQuery ; }
    }
```

The associated queries in the classes are:

```
     public string StudentsInsertQuery  = " INSERT INTO AddStudents (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo, EmailId) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @PhoneNo, @EmailId) ";
    public string StudentsUpdateQuery  = " UPDATE AddStudents SET(FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, PhoneNo=@PhoneNo, EmailId=@EmailId) ";
    public string StudentsDeleteQuery  = " DELETE FROM AddStudents ";
    public string StudentsSelectQuery  = " SELECT * FROM AddStudents WHERE Id=@ID ";
```

Similar case is with the branch and Schools class. 
I am getting this error :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll . at get {return InsertQuery;} in the DBConnectionClass. I have this single error in my project. Please give me an insight of what is happening and how to handle this exception.

Comment: I see the stack overflow immediately.  Your setter will cause the same exception.   Do you know what a stack overflow is, and how property get/set works?

Comment: You are using the properties wrong. Look up some basic info about get/set to get started :)

Comment: Sorry, your setter as-is will not cause an overflow, but it is completely wrong...

Answer (score 3):

This is infinitely recursive, and will cause a stack overflow:

```
public int MyInt {
    get { return MyInt; }
}
```

`return MyInt;` again calls the `get` accessor for `MyInt`, which tries to `return MyInt;`, which calls the `get` accessor...until the stack is full.

You have not specified any actual storage for your variable.  C# gives you a lovely shortcut for this if you don't need any special behaviors in your get/set:

```
public int MyInt {
    get;
    set;
}
```

C# will create storage for the property behind the scenes.  If you need special behaviors, then you must declare your own storage.  For example:

```
private int m_my_int;
public int MyInt {
    get {
        // maybe do something
        return m_my_int;
    }
    set {
        // maybe do something
        m_my_int = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You code has problems.  Specifically, c# does not have a `property` keyword!

Comment: Argh, you're right.  I spend too much time in C++/CLI-land.  Edited to fix.

Comment: The error got removed using the method above. But the same error is being caused at line where I have instatiated the object Schools schools =new Schools(); I know this method is not completely wrong, it must work someway. can you give me an insight @Brian A. Henning

Comment: @MuhammadShahid it seems to me you would benefit from more study of C#.  Spend some more time trying to understand it on your own, then return to Stack Overflow and ask additional questions if you get stuck again.